# I can't get my form to position right, probably an issue with CSS

Tags: html, css, forms, input, styles

OK, so I'll start by saying that this is the first time I have ever used an HTML form, so I think I've researched them pretty well, and still haven't found anyone with this issue.

That being said, I'm also a amateur at HTML in general, so this is probably just another annoying *please-check-my-code* question.

I have a webpage with the following code:

```css
body {

 margin: 0px;

}

.main-header {

 margin-top: 0px;

}

.wrapper {

 margin: 0px;
 width: 100%;
 height: 1000px;

}

.header {


 background-color: #0FADD1;
 width: 100%;
 height: 200px;

}

.description {

 position: absolute;
 margin: auto;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 background-color: #0FADD1;

}

h1, h2, h3, h4, p {

 font-family: Arial, sans-serif;

}

h1 {

 font-size: 4em;
}

.save-heading, .save-paragraph, .save-heading-two{

 text-align: center;
 color: white;

}

.save-heading-two {

 margin-top: 100px;
 margin-bottom: 0px;

}

.save-paragraph {

 margin-top: 100px;

}

.calculator {

 background-color: #0E9CC0;
 height: 500px;

}

.calc {

 background-color: white;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

 <html>

  <head>

   <title>Helyos Co.</title>

   <!-- Fonts -->
   <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,100' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

   <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='css/jquery-ui.css'/>
   <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='css/stylesheet.css'>
   

  </head>

  <body>
   
   <div class='wrapper'>

    <div class='header'>
     
     <!-- TODO: Stuff here? -->

    </div>

    <div class='description'>

     <h1 class='save-heading'>You could save ##$ a year <br> by switching one bulb.</h1>
     <p class='save-paragraph'>Now multiply that times the average<br>number of lightbulbs in a home.<br>And remember, air conditioning makes a
     <br> difference. Also, how many kilowatts do you use?<br>You know what?</p>
     <h2 class='save-heading-two'>Just use our Handy Dandy Calculator to do it for you</p>

    </div>

    <div class='calculator'>

     <form class='calc-form'>
      
      <input type='number' class='calc' name='watt-hours' placeholder='Enter a number'/>

     </form>

    </div>

   </div>

   <script type='text/javascript' charset='UTF-8' src='js/jquery-ui.js'></script>
   <script type='text/javascript' charset='UTF-8' src='js/jquery-2.2.0.js'></script>
   <script type='text/javascript' src='js/script.js'></script>

  </body>

 </html>
```

Before I add my CSS, it looks like this:

[image]

which has the form in the right spot. But if you run my code, you'll see that the form migrates to the upper left-hand corner of the screen and becomes invisible except for the arrow buttons. I know this has something to do with my CSS, but I'm not sure what.

**EDIT**--------------------------------------------------

JS-Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/kairocks2002/m3eaqekr/)

**EDIT 2**------------------------------------------------

[image: As you can see, the form is above all other elements.]

Comment: Can u provide a fiddle

Comment: Yeah, I'll edit the post.

Comment: Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/96rkdL6j/).. didnt get your question..could you please explain a bit more clearly..

Comment: Fiddle included at the bottom of the answer now

Comment: I think the code is working fine

Comment: Are you running it in Safari? Because for some reason or another my form pops up above all the other elements. I'll include a picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, thanks for giving lots of information and putting up a fiddle - helps a ton to help you.  Having said that, I am not certain of the what the problem is, but it looks like some content is getting covered.  I have a good guess at what is messing you up.  You are making your .description class `position:absolute` which is makes a major change in the rendering.  You can think of absolute positioning as removing that element from the normal flow of the webpage and pasting it on top of the page at the location you specify.  In other words, if you place it over something else on the page, that other item will be hidden.  It is very useful for modals and pop-ups and things that are supposed to cover other content.  for a normal web flow, you would typically not use absolute (lots of exceptions of course).

when i changed your `position:absolute` to `position:relative` , i could see your form, etc.  if you are trying to accomplish something that requires absolute, maybe you can specify that goal in your question.